# How could I send a message to someone through my wifi network?

Tags: wifi-configuration

How can I send a message to an iPhone from a Windows machine through WiFi?

Comment: If you want a valid excuse to change the password, read your terms of service from your provider. Odds are good that you're not strictly adhering to them. Make it a white lie and say that you were presented with the evidence of "outside use" and had to change the password.

Comment: Actually, what you are trying to do is possible, but not with an iPhone. You can send messages to other Windows users and computers using netmsg, provided they are on your network. See answer below. Does she have a laptop at all? Then you may be in luck

Comment: As an aside, if you wanted to be really devious, you could change your DNS to redirect all web requests to a webpage you set up online. You could put whatever you wanted on it, and whenever she went online, she would be directed there. This would work with any device, not just a computer.

Comment: Thanks to fixer's edit, these comments read quite strangely out-of-context...

Answer (score 5):

It's *(virtually)* **impossible**.

It would be a very big security flaw if anyone on a network could just run some code and make some message appear on my phone, unsolicited, don't you think?
If that were possible, for instance, you could send prank/spam/virus messages to anyone on any somewhat public network you've ever been on. 
Think airports, starbucks, etc.

And the only reason I added the "virtually" there is because, technically, with a lot of resources, skills, money and some zero-day vulnerabilities, it could be possible, but that's way beyond the realm of real life in any practical scenario.

But a somewhat obvious solution could be: just change the password, she will come by again to ask about the change. Get your tape.

Or ask the neighbors as well.

Comment: You could always change the name of the AP.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to qualify Vinicius's answer. It is possible to send messages to other *computers* on your network. You may be out of luck in this case, but it is otherwise totally possible to do this.

This was (and is) possible with the `net send` command.

`net send` has since been superceded by `msg`. On a domain, you can simply type `msg username message` at the Command Prompt and your message will be sent to that user. You can also target a computer instead of a username.

I have heard `msg` is restricted to certain versions of Windows (it works for me, but I'm on a domain right now), so you may have better luck with the following Microsoft provided tool: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/A-net-messenger-script-for-810f8331

If you download the tool above and unzip the folder, you will see 4 files:
[image]

Run `netmessenger-eng.vbs`. The one beneath that is Portuguese.

This particular tool is setup to send to the entire network, since I am on a domain at present, as you can see below:

[image]

You may have to run enablemsg.vbs if it does not work for you at first.

You can try this tool, but I *highly* doubt it would work with an iPhone. If she had a computer, you might have some more luck.

Comment: Thank for the addition! Maybe that could be someone's use case. =) 
But in his case, still no. Even if she had a computer, luck wouldn't help much. The messenger service (responsible for receiving the 'net send' command), and the equivalent service for receiving the 'msg' command are disabled by default (Ever since WinXp SP2 and subsequent Win versions, precisely for security reasons). 
The very script linked above has the "enablemsg.vbs" included, where the header commentary inside reads: "script enable the use of the MSG utility from other computers" (it creates/changes a registry key). =/

Comment: Also, the very executable program 'msg.exe' is not included in Win 10 Home, only on Win 10 Pro. So even if I were in a managed network, in a domain, with another pc configured and ready to accept my 'msg' command, I wouldn't be able to call that script in my Windows 10 Home Single Language =/
The script gives me an error saying "The specified computer does not exist or can be offline, or you may not have enough privileges(...)" but if you open the VBS you find "objShell.Run("cmd /c msg * /server:" (...)".
It tries to call the msg which I don't have, and that's the true cause of the error.

Comment: @ViníciusM Oops, I thought it probably wouldn't work for him... too bad. I have tried using it on computers on 2 different domains and it has worked for me. So I suppose if someone needs to send a message to someone whom they don't know at their office, and they happen across this answer, it might work for them.